# SharedPreferences string Array not working

Tags: android, preferences, shared

I got two Activitys where I want to save and to load a two String[] Array (Sizes are same).

Code in Activity 1 looks like this (load)

```
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();

    for (int i = 0;i<array_question.length;++i)
     {
         array_question[i] = data.getString("FAE"+i, array_question[i]);
         array_answer[i] = data.getString("ATW"+i, array_answer[i]);

     }
```

Activity two (save)

```
SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();

         for (int i = 0;i<Main.array_question.length;++i)
         {
             editor.putString("FAE"+i,Main.array_question[i]);
             editor.putString("ATW"+i,Main.array_answer[i]);
         }
         editor.commit();
```

I got no error or crash but also no result.When I want to load them there is nothing... What is my fault ?

Comment: You are retrieving from array_question[i] and saving back in array_question[i]. How is it initialized for the first time.?

Comment: I just filled them with the content of a EditText . So Im not saving and loading the same array.They are changing durring the app.